# Возможно ли из нескольких TArray<> собрать один без копирования?

Tags: delphi

Есть библиотека, где функции работают в духе

```
function Foo(Result: TArray<Double>; AnyData: ... )
```

принимая TArray и внутри заполняя его.
Понадобилось сделать единый большой массив из нескольких вызовов Foo, возможно такое без копирования? В голову приходит только объявить большой массив и передавать указатели на его части. Но как такое сделать не пойму. Да и у TArray должна же инфа о длине хранится ещё.

Comment: Правильно рассуждаете, всё так. В "хорошей" библиотеке было бы по типу `aData: Pointer; aDataLength: Integer;`

Answer (score 0):

> В голову приходит только объявить большой массив и передавать указатели на его части.

Хороший вариант, если вы заранее знаете верхнее ограничение на суммарную длину.

> Но как такое сделать не пойму.

Через `SetLength()` устанавливаете нужную длину массива

В функции `Foo` добавляете ещё один параметр `var N: Integer` — количество уже занятых в массиве элементов.

Все обращения `Result[i]` заменяете на `Result[N + i]`

В конце функции `Foo` увеличиваете значение `N` на количество новых элементов.

В вызывающем коде соответственно заводите переменную `N`, и инициализируете её нулём перед первым вызовом `Foo`

> Да и у TArray должна же инфа о длине хранится ещё.

Если речь про количество действительно занятых элементов, то оно будет в переменной `N`.

> возможно такое без копирования?

Только если вы можете заранее определить ограничение на количество элементов. Изменение длины массива в сторону увеличения приводит к неявному созданию нового массива, и копированию элементов в него.

Comment: Правильно, слишком часто вызывать функцию SetLength накладно по времени. Поэтому сначала делаем массив с запасом по размеру, заполняем его и через SetLength ставим уже финальный (реальный) размер.

Comment: @VladChapl, не только по времени, но и по памяти